# Play Sound through mic

Tags: android, telephony

I want to write an application that picks up the phone automatically and preforms an action. I want to be able to play a sound into the microphone in the android device when the incoming call is answered. Can anyone help me with this problem?

I wrote following code to play sound but device, but sound comes out from speaker and I want to play that into the microphone.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.release();
    }
});   

mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without physically modifying the hardware of the device, this is impossible to do.

The Microphone and Earpiece speaker are probably the only part of the phone that is off limits. You can not record audio while a phone call is in progress, and you can not inject data into the voice stream.

Making an answering machine is not a feasible application, as there is no way to handle the phone in this manner.

Comment: i download answering machine from googleplay and play sound is worked

Comment: The thing is you can record the audio but not pass anything to you mic.

Comment: @user2516309 Could you give us a link?